# Can I hide the URL of a page of my website?

Tags: web, url, nfc, fraud-prevention

I have a product with embedded NFC tags for authentication purposes. When a customer scans the tag, they should be taken to a webpage. This webpage should only be accessible by scanning an NFC tag.

Is there a way to hide the URL of the webpage so users can’t navigate to that page without scanning a tag?

Comment: Is each NFC tag unique? (i.e. does it have an unique ID in the URL?

Comment: you want to create [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) ?

Comment: Depends on a whole number of factors including what is scanning the NFC Tag, what type of Tag you are using and how secure you want to to be (Nothing will be totally secure really).

Comment: @blurfus the tags all contain the same URL

Comment: @Andrew I will be using NTAG215. iOS and Android phones will be scanning the tags